# Rendering 2 UL next each other

Tags: css, reactjs

i would like to render the list next each other, i tried few things like inlineblock , float : left
    and it didnt work.
    i will be glad if some one can tell me what to do and explain it to me :)

```
[App][1]
[calling the 2 list components][2]
[first list jsx][3]
[first list css][4]
[second list jsx][5]
[second list css][6]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qyDX.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHmNO.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evWa2.png
      [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WJBl.png
      [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwSqB.png
      [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6LyZ.png
```

Comment: Is it react js or md file???

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to Stackoverflow, please check proper ways to post questions. You have upload the questions and deleted some lines that stops the image loading. And as I went through your code, I would recommend you to set `width:50vw` to both Unordered List. This could get your Lists render as you expect.

Comment: Your right, next time i will post my question in the format.
but i still cant render them side by side after i tried to add width:50vw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your two list components inside a div and then use flex to display them side by side. Try this:

```css
.list-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <div class="person-list">
    Person List
    <ul>
      <li>First item</li>
      <li>Second item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="shwazi">
    Shwazi
    <ul>
      <li>First item</li>
      <li>Second item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display: flex` with these properties alongside with it:

```css
.target {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

this will put `.target` element in a flex condition where items were aligned in center and are next to each other!

also you can use `grid` as well:

```
.target {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, it almost worked but the header is still under the first list and i cant  move it

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting something that I tried, this works as expected. I have added `Home` component and `Contact` component in `App` component. This seems to work. Have this code as an example and try to proceed with your project. You can also check for `flex` in CSS display property, this could also have the same effect. Hope it helps!!.. **Happy Coding!!**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function Home(){
   return (<ul style={{position:'absolute',display:'inline',
   background:'skyblue',width:'50vw',left:0}}>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Home</li>
      </ul>);
}
function Contact(){
  return (<ul style={{position:'absolute',display:'inline',
  background:'red',width:'50vw'}}>
         <li>Contact</li>
         <li>Contact</li>
         <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>);
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Home/>
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}
```